# How to extract a link

Tags: php, html

i have a link that translates from english to rusian.
i want to output just http://wallstreetpit.com/103349-qualcomms-qcom-new-technology-to-triple-wifi-speeds/ but at the same time the link that is output to be translated

```
$url = http://translate.google.com/translate?sl=en&tl=ru&js=y&prev=_t&hl=ro&ie=UTF-8&u=http://wallstreetpit.com/103349-qualcomms-qcom-new-technology-to-triple-wifi-speeds/
```

Comment: where does the link come from? how do you do the output?

Comment: the link is concatenated first part http://translate.google.com/translate?sl=en&tl=ru&js=y&prev=_t&hl=ro&ie=UTF-8&u= and the second  http://wallstreetpit.com/103349-qualcomms-qcom-new-technology-to-triple-wifi-speeds/

Comment: create a new url string containing of "http://translate.google.com/translate?sl=en&tl=ru&js=y&prev=_t&hl=ro&ie=UTF-8&u=".$your_url

Comment: i created but i dont want to output  translate.google.com just the link

Comment: The point of my question: If you already have the link to the page separate there is no need to extract anything. If you only have the complete link including the google translate part there is more to do.

Comment: i have the complete link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put the translate.google url inside the href attribute of an `<a href=""></a>`

And output it like so
`<a href="translate.googleurl">Thewallstreetlink</a>`